# Eclipse with php7.0 does not stop at breakpoints after ubuntu 16 upgrade

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug

I have been researching this for about half a day, and still have not found an answer. There are many many fixes for Eclipse PDT when it does not stop at breakpoints. None of the fixes have worked.

Here are the main points:

PHP Version 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Eclipse Luna 4.4.2

Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0RC2, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans

So we can see that xdebug is correctly installed and phpinfo() shows this.

here is part of my php.ini

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp/xdebug/"
xdebug.profiler_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.extended_info=0
```

Some more detail:

```
PHP API     20151012
PHP Extension   20151012
Zend Extension  320151012
Zend Extension Build    API320151012,NTS
PHP Extension Build     API20151012,NTS
```

When I try to debug the php code, it executes all at once (correctly) without stopping at the first line or at any breakpoints or at xdebug_break().

Debug preferences indicate XDebug, php 7.0 and localhost as server. The paths are set correctly and as I mentioned the code does execute, it just does not stop at breakpoints

What else can I look for?

EDIT

I did a fresh install of Eclipse Neon. I created a brand new project in a ndw workspace with one php file with just 3 lines of code. I then went through the debug and server setups so that I have the same server and debug settings I had before the debugger stopped working. This has not changed anything.

I have noticed that after I launch a debug session, the whole script executes properly, but at the bottom of the eclipse window there is a progress where it says: Launching debug.test: (27%) and it stays at 27% and the progress bar goes back and forth.

It would seem that the problem must be related to my php config, which is logical since it began after a system upgrade.

Does anyone know how a php config can cause xdebug to silently stop working?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. xdebug.so was not executable. I fixed it with:

sudo chmod +x /xdebug.so

I hope this will be of use to someone.

Comment: I have the exact same problem but this solution didn't work for me.